# R - Calculate number of row containing specific values

Tags: r, row

I have this data frame and would like to calculate in R how many rows have one "Y", two "Y" etc.

Any advice would be much appreicated.

```
SOC_023 SOC_040 SOC_044 SOC_055 SOC_079 SOC_089 SOC_090
1   N   N   N   N   N   N   N
2   N   N   N   N   N   N   Y
3   N   N   N   N   N   Y   N
4   N   N   N   N   N   Y   Y
5   N   N   N   N   Y   N   N
6   N   N   N   N   Y   Y   Y
7   N   N   N   Y   N   N   N
8   N   N   N   Y   N   N   Y
9   N   N   N   Y   Y   N   N
```

Many thanks,

Artur

Comment: `table(rowSums(df == "Y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out <- apply(your_data, 1, function(x) sum(x == "Y"))
```

which will give you how many "Y" there are in every row. Afterwards you could
for example make a table to see how many rows contain 1 "Y", 2 "Y" etc

```
table(out)
```

Comment: Many thanks!   Is there a way to have a complete overview on this data eg. to see all combination and summary ? For example replace "Y" with 1 and "N" with 0 ... I would appreciate any suggestions and advice how to get the outcome.

Comment: Dont really understand, if you now there are X of "Y" in a row, then there must be number of rows - X of "N"?

Comment: The first row with N's only is a glitch in the data set and it has been removed. There are X numbers of rows with Y's only and number of rows with different combinations  of Y's and N's. The columns represent different subjects so I would like to have a total overview on this dataset. See how many Y's and N's in columns and any possible statistical overview. Not sure if the approach of replacing Y with 1 and N with 0 is necessary. Btw how to replace them ? Thanks a million!

Comment: x[x == "Y"] <- 1